# October cms checkbox list secondary description error

Tags: php, octobercms

I have products and categories tables and product and category models.

As it is written in the [documentation](http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-dropdown):

1) I have added a few lines to "plugins/author/plugin_name/models/product/fileds.yaml" file.

```html
categories:
   label: Categories
   type: dropdown
   options: listCategories
```

2) I also have modified "plugins/author/plugin_name/models/Product.php" file.

```html
public function listCategories()
   {
      $cats = \Db::table('author_plugin_name_categories')->lists('name');
      return $cats;
   }
```

And after that it shows list of categories on my product creation/update page.

Furthermore, I found out that dropdown type supports secondary description, so I can return associative array in the "listCategories" function. This is a great fiture. Unfortunately it works with dropdown type only.

So following problem appeared. I want to apply secondary description to [checkbox list](http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#field-checkboxlist) type of field or to [tag list widget](http://octobercms.com/docs/backend/forms#widget-taglist). Despite of the fact that checkbox list supports secondary description, an error occurs when I'm trying to apply secondary description.
[image]

May be someone can help me to fix it? I want to use secondary description with checkbox list or with tag list widget so I can display list of cats in my product item and save only their ids to products table.

Answer (score 1):

In order to save multiple values, you need to set the model attribute as jsonable in the model file:

```
protected $jsonable = ['categories'];
```

Comment: The jsonable error is thrown when you try to save a model and the some values are of wrong type.
Do you have defined the category relations correctly in your models?

Comment: I just want to implement associative array for checkbox list as well as I can do it fo dropdown list. I want to display values in my checkbox form and only take the keys from them on save event `return ['name_1' => 'Bob', 'name_2' => 'John']`. The problem is that checkbox list doesn;t work in any case even as it shown in docs example.

Comment: You should use relations instead of a manual field (take a look [here](https://octobercms.com/docs/backend/relations))

But if you do it your way and save the category values directly to the product, then you must add  `protected $jsonable = ['categories'];`  to the product model

Comment: Thank you so much, it works now! Exactly what I want. Yes, I want save categories directly to each product.